# htaccess for subfolders to act as root for themselves

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory

I have the following:

```
main
+ project1
+ project2
```

Here main is the document root, and projectXXX are sub folders with separate projects inside

I need an htaccess file added to every subfolder (projectXXX) so when I type html absolute link (ex: `<img src='/images/image.jpg'>`) to point into that folder I am currently in.
I try this
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

But when I type src='/images/image.jpg' it's looking for an image into document root and not "sub folder root"

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In `project1` you would use `RewriteBase /project1`, but you cannot use `/images/foo.jpg` to refer to `project1/images/foo.jpg` - how would Apache HTTPD know in which folder to look for the image?

There is a way however: add this to to your `<head>` in HTML files in `project1/`:

```
<base href="/project1/">
```

See [base tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) for more info.

Comment: I see! I was thinking that when you create the htaccess files and add RewriteBase / when apache access the folder it'll remain in this folder and when you type absolute address like /images/foo.jpg it'll search for the image into that folder and not document root.

Comment: Ah, no, it is simply to shorten the paths you have to type in `RewriteRule`; if you move a folder somewhere else, you'd only have to change the `RewriteBase`.

Comment: Ahhhh now i got it! Thank you. We can close this one.